# Angular 13 cannot import Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just upgraded to angular 13 (**from Angular12**) and RSJS7. Here is portions of my package.json.

"typescript": "^4.4.4",

"@angular/animations": "13.0.2",
"@angular/common": "13.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "13.0.2",
"@angular/core": "13.0.2",
"rxjs": "^7.4.0",
When ever I try to build my angular project I get the error message :

import { Observable }                      from 'rxjs';
Cannot find a declaration for module rxjs
I have installed: npm install @types/rxjs

**tscondig.json**

```
{
     "compileOnSave": false,
     "compilerOptions": {
     "baseUrl": "./",
     "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
     "strict": true,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
     "sourceMap": true,
     "declaration": false,
     "downlevelIteration": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "importHelpers": true,
     "target": "es2017",
     "module": "ES2015",
     "lib": [
       "es2018",
       "dom"
      ],
     "paths":{
       "@app/*":      ["src/app/*"],
       "@services/*": ["src/app/services/*"],
       "@entities/*": ["src/app/entities/*"],
       "@shared/*":   ["src/app/shared/*"]
     
    },
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

But I still get the error.
So what am I missing?

Comment: can you post your tsconfig.json please?

Comment: what is the older version number you upgraded from?

Comment: previous RXJS was 6.xxc

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but you don't need to install `@types/rxjs`. The types come with the `rxjs` library itself

Comment: Yes I already installed it. I still have the problem.

Comment: I noticed that there is a difference in the folder containing RXJS version 6.x.x and 7.x. In the 6.x version I can see where Observable resides. I do not see this in version 7.x

Comment: Final note. The software seems to work but it still has a whole bunch of errors when I use visual code . It could hide errors that prevent a compile.